# Expressing wishes about the present

Tags: past-tense, wish

When one wants to express wishes about the present, future or generally how it should be done. For example how should I say that it would be better to study history of fashion instead of biology: Which one is correct way to saying that?

> I wish I was studying story of fashion instead of biology!
>
> I wish I had studied story of fashion instead of biology!

Comment: Your sentence is in the _indicative_ mood. A prescriptivist would insist instead upon the _subjunctive_ mood: _I wish I **were** studying..._ However, modern (descriptivist) grammars accept both forms. In normal speech and conversation, either one is fine, but in writing, it's probably best to use the subjunctive. Learn to be comfortable with both forms.

Comment: Well @VardanHovhannisyan - now you ask a completely different question! The first sentence presents you as _currently_ studying biology. The second presents you as _finished_ with the study of biology. Both tell us that you think it would be better to study fashion, but only the first leaves open the possibility that you may still switch courses.